# Erro: no implicit conversion of Integer into String (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

**Escolhi a linguagem ruby para aprender a programar porem estou travado no seguinte exercício**:

Escreva um programa que pergunte pelo número favorito de uma pessoa. Some um ao número, e sugira o resultado como um número favorito muito melhor

**só consigo multiplicar o número e não somar**

```
puts 'Olá, qual é seu número favorito ?'
name = gets.chomp
puts 'Seu número favorito é ' + name + '?  Que número legal!'
puts 'Eu acho que, ' + name * 1 + ' é um número favorito muito melhor. :)'
```

**se eu trocar**: `' + name * 1 + '`  **por**  `' + name + 1 + '`

> new.rb:4:in +': no implicit conversion of Integer into String (TypeError)

Comment: Como você tentou? Edite a pergunta e inclua seu código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O retorno de `gets.chomp` é uma `string`.  É necessário converter este dado para inteiro antes de tentar fazer alguma operação aritmética.

Isso é possível usando o método `to_i`. Perceba que para usar a representação em texto do número, será necessário usar o método `to_str`.

```
puts 'Olá, qual é seu número favorito ?'
name = gets.chomp.to_i

puts 'Seu número favorito é ' + name.to_s + '?  Que número legal!'
puts 'Eu acho que, ' + (name + 1).to_s + ' é um número favorito muito melhor. :)'
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso235960)

Comment: Muito obrigado agora eu entendi perfeitamente.